# Search result when user is logged

Tags: search

I have a problem when I make a search with the common search bar, when the user is logged. The result url is http://search/node/%item instead of http://example.com/search/node/%item.

I hope someone can help me, sorry for my english.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you by any chance using this hook hook_url_inbound_alter in you code base to alter the search path.  reference here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7